# How to get check box text in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" >Car</input>
```

How to get text in JQuery ?

not needed any values for checkbox how to get textarea in alert ?

Comment: How to get what text? Please use some punctuation as well.

Comment: that's invalid HTML - the Permitted Content of an input element is None because it's a void element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input - it also states for Tag omission: `Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.`

Comment: An input cannot contain text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Input should not contain any contents. You can do this way:-

#### Markup

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" /><label>Car</label>
```

#### Script

```
$(':checkbox[name=vehicle]').next('label').text();
```

if you are using it in change event: then

```
$(yourcheckbox).on('change', function(){
    var mytext =  $(this).next('label').text();
})
```

Have a read from [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) on the standard way to use label for inputs.

Answer (score 6):

I would put the text after the `input` into a `label` element and get it that way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" />
<label>Car</label>
```

JS:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).next("label").text());
});
```

Comment: haha. man you are right.. :) My +1 too

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = $('input[type="checkbox"]').text();
alert(text);
```

Is this what you wanted?

But really you meant:

```
<p>Car<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle"></p>
```

JS:

```
var text = $('input[type="checkbox"]').parent().text();
alert(text);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work

Comment: @ClaudioRedi It may, have you tried it; And that was the question ;)